# How can I get top 5 values from json which stored in one column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table name `log_requests` where I store json array into `request` column, which is like following

`{"game_id":"1","score":"820",}`

game_ids are 1 to 20, now I want to know which game_id is used many time. To getting count of a game_id I am using following query which is working fine

`SELECT * FROM log_requests WHERE json_contains(request, '{"game_id" : "1"}')`

But how can I get top 5 game_id from this table?

Answer (score 3):

"I shoot myself in a foot, how to create a crutch?"

## Do not store relational data in JSON fields.

Period.

Create a sensible table structure, store your games in a **separate table** and you will never have a problem like this, having your data from a simple conventional SQL

```
select game_id, count(1) cnt from games group by game_id order by cnt desc limit 5
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate your suggestion which is very good. But as you can see I need to fetch record from log_request table which already been created and now in this situation I need to get from same table.+1

Answer (score 0):

As Your Common Sense said its not optimal, but you can solve this by making a temporary table.

Something like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE 
  temp_log_requests
SELECT 
  JSON_EXTRACT(request, '$.game_id') AS game_id,
  ... -- Include the columns you want to use from log_requests here
FROM 
  log_requests 
LIMIT 0;
```

Then in the same session you can query the temporary table like any other.

See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html